# In repository, how to return a double value into list

Tags: c#, linq

i want to list out the amount from linq query

**my code is**

```
public List<OrderMaster> GetAmountByOrder(int orderId)
    {
        var amount = from om in _db.OrderMa
                     join od in _db.Order on om.OrderId equals od.OrderId
                     where om.OrderId == od.OrderId && om.PaymentStatus == false
                     select om.Amount;

        return amount.ToList();
    }


amount.ToList(); error is showing.
```

`cannot implicitly convert type  double to list.....` like that...
how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are declaring your method to return `List<OrderMaster>`, yet you are returning `List<double>`. Also, the join is already equating the `OrderIds`, no need to repeat it in where. And I think that is a bug, because that should be `orderId` from method's parameter. Also, do you want to list of amounts or sum of everything? If the sum then use `Sum` instead of `ToList` and return just `double`.

```
public List<double> GetAmountByOrder(int orderId)
{
    var amount = from om in _db.OrderMa
                 join od in _db.Order on om.OrderId equals od.OrderId
                 where om.OderId = orderId && om.PaymentStatus == false
                 select om.Amount;

    return amount.ToList();
}
```

Comment: again it is showing an error like `cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<double?> to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<double>'`

Comment: @PoliDev There is difference between nullable double (double?) and normal double. Please, read about nullable types : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<OrderMaster> GetAmountByOrder(int orderId)
{
    var  omCollection = from om in _db.OrderMa
                 join od in _db.Order on om.OrderId equals od.OrderId
                 where om.OrderId == od.OrderId && om.PaymentStatus == false
                 select om;

    return omCollection.ToList();
}
```